# Get values in jsp via spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have JSP called `configoffre` with many values and with table I used `ModalAndView` to pass data, now, I need to send values to only update the table with `listconf`. I'm using tow method in same controller

I'm trying to use Modal, I'm not sure about the solution but that's what I already try

This is the **first method:**

```
    public ModelAndView  getConfTypePage(HttpServletRequest request)
           { 
                ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("configoffre"); 
                mav.addObject("listconf" , apceservice.getMigConf()) ;
                mav.addObject("listrp" , apceservice.getallOffres()) ;
                mav.addObject("listgr" , apceservice.getallGroups()) ;          
                mav.addObject("apcactive" , "active") ;
               return mav ;
           }
```

And this is the second method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/apc/configoffre/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
         public String searchoffer(@RequestParam("search") String des, Model model ) {
             List<Mig_offre_conf> getresult = apceservice.searchoffer(des);
             model.addAttribute("listconf", getresult);
            return "configoffre";

         }
```

I expect to get same interface with updated values in table

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Could you please update your question with Jsp code as well and also if you are facing any exception or generated log you have.

Comment: You will have to fill the model with the other values as well. After the rquest the model is destroyed.

Comment: Ah there is no a solution without loading only values i need so